# How to display several vectors within built-in Prometheus Expression Browser

Tags: prometheus

How can one display several vectors at once within Prometheus' built-in expression browser? It is clearly possible as histogram buckets are displayed in parallel [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLB5m.png)]. However, I have tried all combination of `<>`, `[]`, `()`, `{}` and different separators to no avail.

I have not found anything in the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/) as of yet.

E.g. for a histogram bucket:

[image: Example of a histogram bucket]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only possible to evaluate one expression in a given expression browser panel. If you want multiple expressions, I'd recommend using Grafana.

Comment: I figured this would be the answer. Thanks anyway.